# Passing scope vars to a closure that was declared outside of that scope

Tags: javascript

I really hope this isn't a duplicate.

```
function a(){ b(); } // function a calls function b; but there's no function b in the global scope...

(function(){

    // the purpose was to declare it later because it may collide with user-defined functions
    var b = function(){ console.log('I am function b()'); };

    a(); // doesn't work, obviously
    a.call(this); // also doesn't work
    a.apply(this, []); // doesn't work either

    // neither works
    var scope = { 'b': function(){ return b.apply(this,arguments); } }; 
    with(scope){
        a.call(scope);
    }

    // ... what works then? 

}());
```

Simply put, function `a()` declared globally calls function `b()`. Function `b()` is not declared before `a()` and will not be part of the same scope.

So:

1. We cannot modify function `a()`, nor its location where is defined
2. We cannot declare `b()` in the same scope with `a()`
3. We also cannot `var a = eval(a().toString())` or any likewise cheats

With pure scope handling, is this possible? And if it it's not, what else can we do? 
Just trying to learn some JavaScript here that's all.

Comment: The whole point of writing code this way is to _prevent_ accessing `b` from outside the function.

Comment: All your attempts using `.call` and `.apply` are confusing context with scope. Context is the value of the variable `this`.

Comment: @Barmar Ok so there's no way to do it under this circumstances?

Comment: @Barmar if there really is no way just make it an answer saying there's no way so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it. Variables local to a scope cannot be accessed outside that scope, that's the whole point of scoping. If you want to make the `b()` function visible outside the anonymous function, you need to assign it to an outer variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a function object, it wraps all the enclosing functions and forms the closure. Later, whenever the object being used is not found in the local scope, the enclosing function objects will be searched.

In your case, `a` is declared in the global scope and there are no enclosing functions. When you invoke `a` from the IIFE, `b` will be searched within `a` itself and its enclosing functions and finally in the global scope, which is not found anywhere in that list of scopes. That is why it fails with

```
ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

**Note:** The important thing to be noted here is, when you invoke a function, the scope in which the function was defined will be searched, not where it is invoked from.

So, the answer is NO. Its not possible to do what you are trying to do.